# Linux - find content in a given line

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I have several text files with the general format

```
0
0
0
0
125
0
0
0
0
0
0
3211
0
0

0
0
```

Firstly, I would like to determine which lines in file1.txt contain non-zero elements

```
grep -ne '^[1-9]' file1.txt | cut -f 1 d:
```

I then want to loop through these line numbers in file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt and paste the numbers found to a new file with the format. Each text file has one number per line, although the occassional line has only a newline character

```
file1  file2   file3
125    a num   a num
3211   a num   a num
```

I would use the paste command to append each result to my new text file. However, I am unsure how to grep for the contents of a specific line number. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shell**

```
$ paste -d "  " f1 f2 f3 | grep -v "^0 "
1 101 201
3 103 203
11 111 211
```

**Perl:**

```
$ cat script.pl
open(my $f1, "<", "f1")||die $!; 
open(my $f2, "<", "f2")||die $!; open(my $f3, "<", "f3")||die $!;
while (my $line1=<$f1>) {
    chomp $line1; 
    my $line2 = <$f2>; chomp $line2; my $line3 = <$f3>; chomp $line3;
    next if $line1 =~ /^0*$/;
    print "$line1 $line2 $line3\n"
}
$ perl script.pl
1 101 201
3 103 203
11 111 211
```

**Data:**

```
$ cat f1
0
0
1
0
3
0
11
$ cat f2
0
0
101
0
103
0
111
$ cat f3
0
0
201
0
203
0
211
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this Perl version.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my @rows;
my @i;
my @files = qw/ file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt /;

for my $file (@files) {
  tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $file or die qq{Couldn't open file "$file": $!};
  my @i = grep $file[$_], 0 .. $#file unless @i;
  my @column = @file[@i];
  push @{$rows[$_]}, $column[$_] for 0 .. $#column;
}

print join("\t", @files), "\n";
print join("\t", @{$rows[$_]}), "\n" for 0 .. $#rows;
```